# Is there any open source software for USB Endoscope Borescope Camera?

Tags: 14.04, drivers

Is there any Ubuntu driver for USB Waterproof Endoscope Borescope Inspection Camera?

Comment: It may work with `cheese` or any webcam software.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lsusb`? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/guvcview/

This program worked very well for me.

Comment: That's a recording application not a camera device driver. -1

Comment: This worked with my depstech camera in ubuntu. cheese did not recognize it. Great software